# Технологии высоконагруженных социальных сетей

Tags: apache, nginx, кэширование, php, mysql

Меня давно интересовало, с помощью каких технологий делаются высоконагруженные проекты типа социальных сетей (php). Что лучше nginx или apache? Что нужно делать, чтобы сервер выдержал большую нагрузку и т.д. Стоит ли использовать шаблонизаторы или нет? Тупое кэширование на жесткий диск не подходит для социальных сетей, ведь данные там постоянно меняются. Что должен знать программист пхп социальной сети, чтобы допустим работать вконтакте?

Comment: Это подойдёт? [Особенности высоконагруженных сайтов][1].


  [1]: http://kharchuk.ru/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B8/7-PHP%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/160-highload-sites

Comment: Все на этом php рехнулись?

Answer (score 7):

[Архитектура высоконагруженных систем](http://www.insight-it.ru/highload/) Можете посмотреть из чего состоит Одноклассники, Вконтакте, Ютуб, Фейсбук и тд.

Comment: Где-то в инетах мелькала интересная история о том, что после перехода на Erlang в одном крупном проекте, количество используемых серверов сократилось с 200 (или 2000, не помню точно) до - 2(!). Разработчики всего лишь сменили технологию.

Answer (score 2):

Если интересно,то:

- facebook-php+HipHop (это такая штука, которая превращает php код в c++);
- vkontakte-php, хотя там много различных технологий.

В общем крупные соц сети написаны на php (linkedin по моему на java, если нет-поправьте), хотя на узких местах у них используется C++. Честно, не знаю, что должен знать программист php, чтобы работать вконтакте, но наверняка очень много: фреймворки всякие и другие полезности.

> nginx или apache?

В крупных проектах используют связку nginx и apache.Т.е nginx отвечает за фронт-энд красота(здесь имеются ввиду страницы html,стили,скрипты),а на серверной части стоит apache,он принимает и обрабатывает запросы.Т.е nginx ему передал что-то,а apache обработал)